# what is the purpose of tasks member of 'struct pid' defined in Linux/include/linux/pid.h?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, pid, linux-namespaces

Im trying to understand better how the kernel implement pid namespace .
One of the basic structure that is being used is `struct pid` :

```
struct pid { 
      atomic_t count;
      unsigned int level;
      /* lists of tasks that use this pid */
      struct hlist_head tasks[PIDTYPE_MAX];
      struct rcu_head rcu;
      struct upid numbers[1]; }
```

Now from what I understand numbers array keeps track of the process different pids in different pid namespaces.

What I dont understand is the purpose of `tasks` member.
It says here: [(LWN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779416/what-is-the-relation-between-task-struct-and-pid-namespace) :

> .." This structure contains the ID value, the list of **tasks** having this ID.."

So I understand from this that the **same** pid is **shared** between couple of proccess/tasks .
Now, different proccess/threads can share same tpid/gpid but not the same pid!
So how come there are list of tasks having the same PID? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: There is always only a single element pointed by `pid.tasks[PIDTYPE_PID]`. Tasks do not share the PID but they can share `PGID` and `SID`. They are all on the same array for uniformity and code sharing.

Answer (score 1):

A struct `pid` is the kernel's internal notion of a **process identifier**.
It can identify a process, a thread, as much as a **session** or **process group**. That's why there is a list of task.

It's explained in the kernel code that it's a compromise between :

- store only `pid_t` which don't garantee that the process identified
  is the one you want because pids are reused in a cycle way
- store pointers for each thread of processes, which results in a too big table